# Emulating scroll lock behaviour to trigger USB KVM switch

Tags: usb, keyboard

At work, I use two computers: one Windows machine for intranet and mail, one Ubuntu machine on a separate network for development. In order to easily switch between the two I use a simple USB KVM switch (a Newstar) so I can use a single mouse and keyboard for both machines.

Using the hardware key on the switch itself, I can switch between the two computers. However, I don't want to stretch my arm. That's physical effort, and it's not what IT is for.

On the Windows machine, I can double-tap `Scroll Lock` to trigger the switch to the Ubuntu machine. On the Ubuntu machine, `Scroll Lock` does nothing - `xev` says it sends a KeyPress/KeyRelease event with keycode 78, but the scroll light stays off and more importantly, the switch does nothing.

I have found a solution telling me to add `'add mod3 = Scroll_lock'` to `xmodmap`, but while that makes the light blink it doesn't trigger the switch.

Since I *can* double-tap `Scroll Lock` in text mode and make it trigger the switch, I'm guessing either X doesn't fully forward the keypress or something else swallows the event.

So:

How can I make this work? Or more accurately, how can figure out what sort of input will trigger the switch so I can emulate it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo xmodmap -e "add mod3 = Scroll_Lock"
```

You forgot to add `-e`.